# Linux Rename multiple files with same filename throughout different directories

Tags: linux, rename, filenames, subdirectory

Running `Debain Linux`
I wish to statically rename multiple files all with the same filename, throughout multiple **subfolders**. e.g.:

```
/DIR_1/journal.db

/DIR_2/journal.db

/DIR_3/journal.db

/DIR_4/journal.db
```

How can I rename `journal.db` to `journal.db.old` in each directory? (approx. 200)

I have researched renaming scripts and commands but none seem to address the fact i need to do this in multiple directories simultaneously

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think

`$ find -iname "journal.db" -exec rename journal.db journal.db.old '{}' \;`

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's the answer to my own question:

To delete the journal.db file from my example, i used command:

```
find . -name "journal.db" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will delete journal.db from the current folder and sub folders from where you run the command.

To rename the file i used:

```
find ./ -type f -iname 'journal.db' -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%..db}.bad"' _ {} \;
```

This renames it to journal.bad